# Improperly routed Rails Destroy method on nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, destroy, nested-resources

I have a List object, with nested Tasks. I have created a page that displays individual tasks, and also a page that allows a user to edit individual tasks. I now want to add the ability to delete a task from a list on the tasks edit page. Using the following code

```
<%= link_to 'Delete this task',@task, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

yields

```
undefined task_path method
```

This code is on the show.html.erb page, where I call @task to display all of the data stored within the task, so I believe that this issue may be a routing error of some kind, however I cannot seem to figure it out.

The related controller method is

```
def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to list_tasks_path(@task) }
        format.json { head :ok }
    end
end
```

I thought that with the delete method the @task I supplied would just be sent to the destroy method via params, but this error seems to be showing that this isn't exactly how it works. So how can I properly destroy a nested resource in Rails?

**edit:**
Here is the route file with nested resources:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :lists do
        resources :tasks
    end
    get "home/index"

    root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since it's a routes problem, please add your `routes.rb` to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have @list setup, or use @task.list (assuming you have a belong to relationship), and you could do the following:

```
<%= link_to "Delete this task", list_task_path(@task.list, @task), confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete %>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete this task', list_task_path(@list, @task), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

Or if you want it more compact (like you've written it):

```
<%= link_to 'Delete this task', [@list, @task], confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

Either way, since it's a nested resource, you must pass in both the `@list` and `@task` objects.